# Fixed Sized Buffer or Variable Buffers with C# Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, protocol

I am busy designing a TCP Server class in C# that has events and allows the user of the class to define packets that the server can send a receive by registering a class that is derived from my "GenericPacket" class. My TCPListener uses Async methods such as .BeginReceive(..);

My issue is that because I am using the .BeginReceive(); I need to specify a buffer size when I call the function. This means I cant read the whole packet if one of my defined packets is too big. I have thought of creating a fixed sized Header that gets read using .BeginRead(); and the read the rest using Stream.Read(); but this will lead to the whole server having to wait for this operation to complete.

I would like to know if anyone has come across this before and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but have you considered using C# 5.0 [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175)? It can make your code much simpler, when compared with using methods like `BeginReceive()`.

Comment: Also, can't you just use `Stream.BeginRead()` for everything?

Comment: @svick then I will have a hell of a lot of callback methods because I need one for each type of packet.